# How to purge old records from a table automatically using shell script

Tags: sql, shell, unix, plsql

I have a main table which is having sub partition month wise based on date condition.I have a request for purging out the old records from this main table keeping only the last 24 months of records along with max value and default sub partition.
How to write a shell script with a SQL query for this ?

Comment: What is your problem here? How to write a shell script? How to dynamically drop the partitions? Incidentally, why a shell script and not a dbms_scheduler job?

Comment: As has been already pointed out, you could use a job programmed on the Oracle DB scheduler to perform the task. You could also use a SQL script a program a cron (if you're using linux, similar options available for windows) to run the script periodically. There are multiple ways to perform the task. What is it that you are asking?